# Chaining multiple promises, including Promise.all

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, angular-promise, jszip

I have a requirement which requires chaining of Promises. In my Ionic app, I need to iterate over a list of files and zip them. Then the zip needs to be stored on the device itself (iPhone in this case).

I already have the list of files that need to be zipped in an array. So, I am iterating over them and using $cordovaFile getting the binay content of these files. Then I am adding binary to a JSZip object. End result should be that binary content of all the files should be added to zip.file, so that a zip file can be generated.

```
//wrapping in Promise.all so that we don't proceed until we have the content of all files added to zip
var zip = new JSZip();
return Promise.all(
        filesList.forEach(function(file) {
           console.log('file to be added using $cordovaFile '+file); 
           // Getting the content of each file using $cordovaFile. This returns a promise. 
                  return $cordovaFile.readAsBinaryString(cordova.file.dataDirectory + $rootScope.username, file)
                       .then(function(binaryData) {
                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                         //Adding content of all files to zip.file so that it can be zipped in the next step.
                            resolve(zip.file(file, binaryData, {binary: true}));
                        })        
                      })
                      .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log('Error during fetch content or zipping '+JSON.stringify(error));
                      })
                 })
             )
```

Once zip.file has all the contents, I am calling another function in JSZip which would generate the zip. This would return a promise as well, so I need to chain to $cordovaFile.writeFile, so that the zip can be written locally. $cordovaFile.writeFile also returns a Promise which would the last promise in the chain.

```
.then(function(zipData) {
// async request to generate the zip
                return zipData.generateAsync({type:"blob"});
            }).then(function (blob) {
  // once we have the zip, save it to the device 
                $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory+$rootScope.username, 'abc.zip', blob, true)
                .then(function(data) {
                   console.log('Zip file written to device at '+cordova.file.dataDirectory+$rootScope.username); 
                })
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error while zipping and writing '+JSON.stringify(error));
            })
```

This is how the complete code looks like

```
var zipFiles = function(filesList) {
var zip = new JSZip();

             return Promise.all(
                filesList.forEach(function(file) {
                   return $cordovaFile.readAsBinaryString(cordova.file.dataDirectory + $rootScope.username, file)
                      .then(function(binaryData) {
                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                            resolve(zip.file(file, binaryData, {binary: true}));
                        })        
                      })
                      .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log('Error during fetch content or zipping '+JSON.stringify(error));
                      })
                 })
             )
            .then(function(zipData) {
                return zipData.generateAsync({type:"blob"});
            }).then(function (blob) {
                $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory+$rootScope.username, 'abc.zip', blob, true)
                .then(function(data) {
                   console.log('Zip file written to device at '+cordova.file.dataDirectory+$rootScope.username); 
                })
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error while zipping and writing '+JSON.stringify(error));
            }) 
}
```

Challenge is that after Promise.all completes, nothing gets executed. So, nothing starting 'then(function(zipData)' gets executed.

I feel it has something to do with the way I am chaining Promises. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `forEach` returns `undefined`, thus `Promise.all` resolves immediately. You should change that to `.map`.

Moreover, keep in mind that your `zipData` argument would not be what you expect. This promise's arguments will contain every result returned from `zip.file(file, binaryData, {binary: true})`.

In this case you do not need the `zipData`. The `zip` variable will do the job. In the code bellow I have also simplified the promises chain by removing a redundant promise in the loop and taking one `.then` outside.

```
var zipFiles = function (filesList) {
    var zip = new JSZip();

    var zipFilesPromises = filesList.map(function (file) {
        return $cordovaFile.readAsBinaryString(cordova.file.dataDirectory + $rootScope.username, file)
            .then(function (binaryData) {
                return zip.file(file, binaryData, { binary: true });
            });
    }); 

    return Promise.all(zipFilesPromises)
        .then(function () {
            return zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" });
        })
        .then(function (blob) {
            return $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory + $rootScope.username, 'abc.zip', blob, true);
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log('Zip file written to device at ' + cordova.file.dataDirectory + $rootScope.username);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error while zipping and writing ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        })
}
```

Comment: Thank you Georgi-it, for not only answering the question but also helping correct other mistakes in my approach which I was not even aware of.

Comment: Glad I could help @kayasa

Answer (score 0):

The reason Promise.all never resolves is that `filesList.forEach` never returns any values.

I think modifying to `fileList.map` will solve your issue.

So change your code as follows:

```
var zipFiles = function(filesList) {
var zip = new JSZip();
return Promise.all(
        filesList.map(function(file) {
               return $cordovaFile.readAsBinaryString(cordova.file.dataDirectory + $rootScope.username, file)
                  .then(function(binaryData) {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        resolve(zip.file(file, binaryData, {binary: true}));
                    })        
                  })
                  .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('Error during fetch content or zipping '+JSON.stringify(error));
                  })
             })
         )
        .then(function(zipData) {
            return zipData.generateAsync({type:"blob"});
        }).then(function (blob) {
            $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory+$rootScope.username, 'abc.zip', blob, true)
            .then(function(data) {
               console.log('Zip file written to device at '+cordova.file.dataDirectory+$rootScope.username); 
            })
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error while zipping and writing '+JSON.stringify(error));
        }) 
}
```